# The usage of 於 in this title

Tags: usage

May I ask what function does the word 於 have in this title: 台北兩日兩夜「帶於媽遊台北」.

I get the general idea of this title: Two Days and Two Nights in Taipei // Bringing my mum to travel around Taipei.

Please give more examples on how to use 於.

Comment: 帶媽媽遊台北  would make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

於 as a surname is extremely rare

I suspect it is a mistake caused by translating the traditional  character 于 (a common surname) as simplified 於  back to the traditional character

[Traditional --> Simplified --> Traditional]

於是 --> 于是  --> 於是

于媽 --> 于妈 --> 于媽 (於媽 is a mistake)

Similarly:

頭髮 --> 头发 --> 頭髮 (頭發 is a mistake)

心臟 --> 心脏 --> 心臟 (心髒 is a mistake)

胡鬚 --> 胡须 --> 胡鬚 (胡須 is a mistake)

In Cantonese, calling a woman by her [last name + 媽] is a common practice, if someone is a friend of 于先生, he might refer 于先生 as 老于 and his mother 于媽.

It is more common to use the first name though, e.g. 阿強的母親是強媽

Also, you can use the nickname, e.g. 阿牛的母親是牛媽

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8Yws3Tm6Wk, it seems that "於媽" is a person's name (or just how this youtuber calls his mother). There are many comments like "於媽笑聲好有感染力", "於媽好正呀" and "於媽真的好好，很開朗~". By the way, the youtuber uses Cantonese in the video and the description.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I am learning cantonese, hence watching these things help a lot in learning. The down side is they speak so fast (and there are no subtitles), so I can understand like 50% of the conversation. The rest are just guessing the context of the statements.

Comment: "於" is also a surname. If used as some sort of preposition in the sentence in question, then it makes no sense, hence Tang Ho's comment. Perhaps his father has more than one wife, and she is not his birth mother. In my family, my siblings from a different mother, called my birth mother by her surname paired with the Cantonese word for "Auntie"

Answer (score 1):

於 in 於媽 might be the person's surname. In Chinese, surname + 称呼 is commonplace, e.g. 王婆，王妈,  李奶奶, 张爷爷, etc.

Have fun!